# How do I set constraints more dynamically in Scipy optimization?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, portfolio

I am trying to minimize the objective function while setting constraints such that all the elements in x are the same. My challenge is that the number of elements in x is not fixed. Right now, I have constraint1: x[0] = x[1], constraint2: x[1] = x[2], etc. However, the number of elements could grow, and I can't preset all the constraints. I was wondering if I could use a loop to set these constraints more dynamically?

```
'Minimize risks'
def objective(x):
    x = np.matrix(x)     
    return x.dot(covariance_matrix).dot(x.transpose())

'Make sure weight_AC equals weight_BB'
def constraint1(x):
    x = np.matrix(x)
    return np.float(x[0,0]) - np.float(x[0,1])


'Make sure weight_BB equals weight_GS'
def constraint2(x):
    x = np.matrix(x)    
    return np.float(x[0,1]) - np.float(x[0,2])

'Make sure weight_GS equals weight_AAPL'
def constraint3(x):
    x = np.matrix(x)   
    return np.float(x[0,2]) - np.float(x[0,3])

'Total weight equals 1'
def constraint4(x):
    x = np.matrix(x)   
    result = 1
    for i in range(0,x.size):        
        result = result - x[0,i]
    return result

con1 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint1}
con2 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint2}
con3 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint3}
con4 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint4}

cons = ([con1, con2, con3, con4])


solution = minimize(objective,x0,method='SLSQP',constraints = cons)
```

Comment: If the constraints are that all elements of the vector optimization variable should be equal, then you could reformulate your optimization problem as a single-dimensional one (optimize over a scalar variable). Wouldn't this make things much easier?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Stelios. Do you mean x1 = x2 = x3 ... xn = 1/n? I am not sure how I can formulate this into one constraint. Could you give me an example?

Comment: I am saying that you can always rewrite a function `f(x1,x2,...,xn)` where `x1=x2=...=xn` as `g(x1)` (think about it). Now, if, in addition, you impose that the sum of `x`'s equals `1`, then I guess you don't need to bother with the optimization as the only values that satisfy the constraints are, as you said, `x1=x2=...=xn=1/n`.

Comment: But is there any way i can use a function such that f(x1, x2, ...,xn) to represent x1 = x2 = x3... = xn?